# curl in windows read function returned funny value

Tags: windows, curl

I am using the following command to upload file to an endpoint

```
curl -X POST -H "authorization: Basic base64encode" -H "Content-Type: 
multipart/form-data" -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F 
"file=@c:/Users/User/Desktop/testresults.xml"  https://jira.test- 
server.ag/rest/api/latest/issue/man-287/attachments
```

the command under mac works without problems, under windows I become the following error

```
curl: (26) read function returned funny value
```

curl version

```
curl 7.64.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1a
```

installed using `https://chocolatey.org`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem when I used `curl` on the Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10. I had to change the path from `C:\Temp\File.txt` to `/mnt/c/Temp/File.txt`.

Check if you can access the file in your shell e.g. with `dir c:\path\to\file.txt` and if it fails then you know that you have to fix the path first.